# Converting the type information supplied by upshot js to that required by JSON.NET in a web api submit

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, upshot

I am attempting to use ASP.NET MVC 4 beta together with JSON.NET.  I'm using upshot to talk to web api.  However when upshiot does a submit it sends the type information in the change set as (for example `"__type":"EquipmentClass:#RXSteps.StepModel.Equipment"` instead of `"$type":"RXSteps.StepModel.Equipment.EquipmentClass, RXSteps.StepModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"` which is what JSON.NET wants.

at the moment I have hacked upshot with 
`encodedChangeSet= encodedChangeSet.replace(/"__type":"EquipmentClass:#RXSteps.StepModel.Equipment"/g, '"$type":"RXSteps.StepModel.Equipment.EquipmentClass, RXSteps.StepModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"');`

However I would like to know how I could do this in a generic way for any type.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your own UpshotJSONMediaTypeFormatter and do the conversion in there.  Henrik has a post on using a JSON.NET media type formatter [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx).  I would just customize the OnReadFromStreamAsync method to do your replace before deserializing.